# Facebook API: allow my own website to access my profile, semi-permanently

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Essentially I want to have my blog grab wall photos, status updates, etc. from my facebook profile. I know how the Javascript sdk works: the user clicks on a special facebook button which then gives my website permissions, for some short duration. I'm using it to grab the display picture of people who post on my website to show next to their comments.

However, this is a somewhat different use case: I'll be the only one person giving permission to my website, and it will be for the long term (weeksish?). I can easily hack together a client-side authentication flow for myself to go and click on and accept, I was wondering if there was a better way to manage this sort of thing? Some backdoor where I, as a facebook user, can manually "give permission" to my website to do stuff.

EDIT: I looked through the app permissions management page on my facebook, and although I can remove app permissions and see what permissions they have and have been using, there is no way to *add* more permissions manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create an app at https://developers.facebook.com/apps
2. Choose that app in the dropdown at the top right of the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and get an access token from that app.
3. CLick 'Get access token' and give it whatever permissions you think you'll nee to access the data you want.
4. Accept the permissions
5. Copy/paste the generated access token into your code and you're done

If the token ever expires (e.g. you change password or your account is locked for security reasons) just generate a new token using the same steps

Comment: This is not currently a correct answer to the question. Following these steps to the letter results in an access token that expires in an hour.

Comment: Yes, my answer was posted over two years ago; there have been many changes to the API since then - you'll now need to extend the access token to a long-lived token using the App ID and App Secret via this method: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#refreshtokens

In general, starting with the documentation and looking at other resources only when you can't find the answer in the docs is probably a good idea

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog/

this shows how to use the showPermissionDialog method on FB Connect. I believe the permission you are looking for is `offline_access`.

Comment: I think I know how to do that. I was just wondering if there was any way to give my own site offline access with myself and manage it, rather than having to go through the normal workflow and make a special button for myself to click =D